# Automatically convert between switch case and if else (in C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I am looking for a tool or an extension to visual studio that would allow easy conversion between switch case and if else statements.

I have tried to search on google but I mostly find performance discussions related to switch case and if else. I also found that Eclipse or InelliJ have support for this, but it does not work for C#.

Comment: Why not write one yourself?

Comment: Resharper can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [RefactoringEssentials](http://vsrefactoringessentials.com/Features/Refactorings-CSharp)

### Edit

The repository link is now https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials.

But it has been shutdown because IDEs now provide refactoring utilities by default. If you need more custom refactoring options, take a look at this repo https://github.com/ironcev/awesome-roslyn#open-source-analyzers-code-fixes-and-refactorings

Comment: Amazing! Works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a domain parking now